# Toggle explorer window

Tags: netrw

neovim 0.2-dev

`:Lexplore` opens up explorer window and entering `:Lexplore` again toggles it. However, if I interact with the explorer window(i.e. expand a directory), then typing `:Lexplore` opens up another explorer window instead of closing the existing one.

[image: Lexplore opens up a new explorer]

Is this the expected behavior? Is there any command/function that will toggle explorer even if the window had interaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try v162j of netrw which may have fixed this problem: http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW

Answer (score 11):

I followed this script (https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/6jcyfj/toggle_lexplore_properly/djdmsal/) and it works as expected.

```
let g:NetrwIsOpen=0

function! ToggleNetrw()
    if g:NetrwIsOpen
        let i = bufnr("$")
        while (i >= 1)
            if (getbufvar(i, "&filetype") == "netrw")
                silent exe "bwipeout " . i 
            endif
            let i-=1
        endwhile
        let g:NetrwIsOpen=0
    else
        let g:NetrwIsOpen=1
        silent Lexplore
    endif
endfunction

" Add your own mapping. For example:
noremap <silent> <C-E> :call ToggleNetrw()<CR>
```

Answer (score 6):

Once this works, each time `Lexplore` is toggled on, it will create a new buffer but not wipe the previous one.

A solution is to wipeout netrw buffers when they are hidden.

```
augroup AutoDeleteNetrwHiddenBuffers
  au!
  au FileType netrw setlocal bufhidden=wipe
augroup end
```

Then, `Lexplore` does work as intended.

See [bufhidden](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#%27bufhidden%27).

Comment: Is there a way to set that for the Vexplore too?

Comment: This should work for any `netrw` buffer, however you opened it.

Answer (score 3):

Updating the version of the netrw plugin indeed fixes the problem, as stated in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11012/11968).

On my Vim v8.0 (installed with Homebrew), I had netrw v156 (find out with `:echo g:loaded_netrwPlugin`), and the mentioned problem existed. You can find the newest version of netrw on [Dr. Chip's website](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW) (currently v165b, updated on 13 March 2019). Installing this version fixed the problem for me (confirming what is stated in the [other answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/11012/11968) that the problem should have been fixed in v162j).

Here is how to install the newest version of the netrw plugin:

1. Go to http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW
2. Click on the title, this should download a file named `netrw.vba.gz`
3. The `netrw.vba` file contained in the downloaded archive is a [vimball](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1502) file. A vimball file is something like a self-installing plugin. Note that you don't have to unzip the `.gz` file, as this is done automatically in the next step.
4. Install the plugin (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033078/how-to-install-a-vimball-plugin-with-vba-extension) or [here](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#VimFuncs) or by `:help vimball`):

   1. Open the vimball file with Vim: `vim netrw.vba.gz`
   2. In Vim, run: `:source %`

The above command installs the components of the plugin to their proper locations in one of your Vim directories (most probably `~/.vim`).

After the installation, you can restart Vim and test if the new version of the plugin has been correctly installed:

```
:echo g:loaded_netrwPlugin
```

This should output `v165b` now (or whatever version you have installed).

Answer (score 2):

I tried several times and it seems once you have interacted with the content, it opens a new window when `:Lexplore` is called again like you stated above, however, it could be a desired behavior when you just want to explore multiple directories at once, why not use 
`:NERDTree` instead if you just want to keep a single && browser?

Comment: Hey thank you for looking into this. `netrw` does everything I need for exploring and interacting with files and directories. I don't want to install a plugin only for toggling behavior.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this behavior here, tried to open and close several directories and open files, but `:Lexplore` simply works. What exactly have you guys done to get that?

Comment: Try with the latest neovim 0.2-dev or Vim 7.4

Answer (score 2):

Full solution (Vexplore + buffer resize + conf) based on different answers and my own experimentation. Togglecode taken from:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5006950/setting-netrw-like-nerdtree
[image]

```
function! ToggleVimExplorer()
  if exists("t:expl_buf_num")
      let expl_win_num = bufwinnr(t:expl_buf_num)
      if expl_win_num != -1
          let cur_win_nr = winnr()
          exec expl_win_num . 'wincmd w'
          close
          exec cur_win_nr . 'wincmd w'
          unlet t:expl_buf_num
      else
          unlet t:expl_buf_num
      endif
  else
      exec '1wincmd w'
      Vexplore 
      " After switching to netwr buff, lets resize to 45
      vertical resize 45
      let t:expl_buf_num = bufnr("%")
  endif
endfunction

nmap <leader>9 :call ToggleVimExplorer()<cr>

function! NetrwMapping()
    " noremap <buffer> <C-l> <C-W>l
    " noremap <buffer> <C-h> <C-W>h

    let g:netrw_banner = 0 " remove the banner at the top
    let g:netrw_liststyle = 3  " default directory view. Cycle with i 
    let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
    let g:netrw_altv = 1
    let g:netrw_sort_sequence = '[\/]$,*

    let g:netrw_list_hide= '.*.swp$, 
            \ *.pyc$,
            \ *.log$,
            \ *.o$,
            \ *.xmi$,
            \ *.swp$,
            \ *.bak$,
            \ *.pyc$,
            \ *.class$,
            \ *.jar$,
            \ *.war$,
            \ *__pycache__*'

endfunction

augroup netrw_mapping
    autocmd!
    autocmd filetype netrw call NetrwMapping()
augroup END
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se] and thanks for writing a thoughtful answer!

Comment: `g:netrw_sort_sequence` values is missing the closing quote. Couldn't suggest edit since the change is less than 6 chars.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that worked for me after I looked at the code for netrw.vim
Seems like `:Rexplore` will look if the variable `w:netrw_rexlocal` exists, if it doesn't (which happens when you have a netrw window that didn't come from a buffer window) it will cause a warning to appear on screen. Seems that there is a `w:netrw_rexfile` variable being set though, which you can use to return the editing file.

```
function ToggleExplorer()
    if &ft == "netrw"
        if exists("w:netrw_rexfile")
            if w:netrw_rexfile == "" || w:netrw_rexfile == "NetrwTreeListing"
                quit
            else
                exec 'e ' . w:netrw_rexfile
            endif
        else
            if exists("w:netrw_rexlocal")
                Rexplore
            else
                quit
            endif
        endif
    else
        Explore
    endif
endfun
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! A little explanation with the code would go a long way. Also: `exec 'q'` is just `quit`; you only need `execute` when you're building up commands from strings or to protect commands from consuming `|`.

Comment: Thank you Ben, added the explanation, the way I found my solution was to read the netrw.vim script, since I wanted to supress the warning that was displayed when using Rexplore

Answer (score 0):

Based on alwc's answer without using global state. This way it doesn't get out of sync when Netrw was open manually first. It will still "glitch" when opening Netrw manully after it was opend with this function. But there is nothing one can do about manual commands I guess.

```
function! ToggleNetrw()
        let i = bufnr("$")
        let wasOpen = 0
        while (i >= 1)
            if (getbufvar(i, "&filetype") == "netrw")
                silent exe "bwipeout " . i
                let wasOpen = 1
            endif
            let i-=1
        endwhile
    if !wasOpen
        silent Lexplore
    endif
endfunction
map <F3> :call ToggleNetrw() <CR>
```

Additionally you can set some defaults

```
augroup ProjectDrawer
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * :Vexplore
augroup END
let g:netrw_banner=0        " disable annoying banner
let g:netrw_winsize = 18    " width in percent
let g:netrw_browse_split=4  " open in prior window
let g:netrw_altv=1          " open splits to the right
let g:netrw_liststyle=3     " tree view
" ret g:netrw_list_hide=netrw_gitignore#Hide()
" let g:netrw_list_hide.=',\(^\|\s\s\)\zs\.\S\+'
" check: |netrw-browse-maps| for more mappings
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a pretty "elegant" solution. You can close a vim buffer by name so all you need is to get the buffer name for Netrw. The only problem is that Netrw doesn't have a buffer name out of the box - so we tell it to have one.

I have it do a vertical split in tree view, and I don't know if the buffer name changes with the configuration. If it doesn't work, try replacing 'NetrwTreeListing' with the name you get after running `:ls`.

```
let g:netrw_active = 1
function! Togglenetrw()
    if g:netrw_active
        Vexplore
        let g:netrw_active = 0
    else
        " This is the name of the buffer
        bd NetrwTreeListing 
        let g:netrw_active = 1
    endif
    return 1
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <C-f> :call Togglenetrw()<CR>

" This is where we tell Netrw to have a buffer name
" (everything is default except 'buflisted')
let g:netrw_bufsettings = 'noma nomod nonu nowrap ro buflisted'

" This is my config
let g:netrw_liststyle = 3
let g:netrw_banner = 0
let g:netrw_browse_split = 4
let g:netrw_winsize = 20
let g:netrw_altv = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this keymap, I'm using Control + N, but you can change it:

```
vim.keymap.set('n', '<C-n>', function()
    if vim.bo.filetype == 'netrw' then
        vim.cmd 'bwipeout'
    else
        vim.cmd 'Explore'
    end
end, { silent = true })
```