# How to open directory in toggled netrw window?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, netrw

I've toggled netrw explorer window by adding the following commands found in an answer posted to [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10988/toggle-explorer-window) question to the vimrc file.

```
let g:NetrwIsOpen=0

function! ToggleNetrw()
    if g:NetrwIsOpen
        let i = bufnr("$")
        while (i >= 1)
            if (getbufvar(i, "&filetype") == "netrw")
                silent exe "bwipeout " . i 
            endif
            let i-=1
        endwhile
        let g:NetrwIsOpen=0
    else
        let g:NetrwIsOpen=1
        silent Lexplore
    endif
endfunction
```

And I have autocmd calling `ToggleNetrw()` with the following.

```
augroup ProjectDrawer
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * :call ToggleNetrw()
    autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
augroup END
```

But when a directory is opened in vim from the terminal (in my case: `vim .`) it opens the directory in the editor window.

[image]

And When a file is selected and opened it is displayed the toggled explorer window.

[image]

Is there a way to make vim open directories in the toggled netrw window?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! *"I've toggled netrw explorer window using the answer posted to this question."* Please indicate which commands exactly you have in your vimrc or that you executed. It's hard to guess, from a question that's not really directly related. Try to make your question stand on its own, even when you refer to other questions for additional context. Please [edit] your question to include the commands you used.

Comment: Do you invoke `ToggleNetrw()` at Vim startup? Do you have an autocmd calling it?

Comment: I have autocmd calling it.


    `augroup ProjectDrawer
        autocmd!
        autocmd VimEnter * :call ToggleNetrw()
        autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
    augroup END`

Comment: Please [edit] the question with your update. It's easier to find the information there rather than in the comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by editing the part calling `ToggleNetrw()`

From:

```
augroup ProjectDrawer
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * :call ToggleNetrw()
    autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
augroup END
```

To:

```
augroup ProjectDrawer
    autocmd!
    if argc() == 1 && isdirectory(argv()[0]) && !exists("s:std_in")
        silent exe "bwipeout " . bufnr("$")
        exe 'cd '.argv()[0]
        autocmd VimEnter * :call ToggleNetrw()
    else
        autocmd VimEnter * :call ToggleNetrw()
        autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
    endif
augroup END
```

Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: This looks like it makes `vim . and_other_file` and `vim some_other_dir` hard to actually do

Comment: You're right but they were not working properly before the editing either. any suggestions?

Comment: Dogmatically, I would say read http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/; practically I don’t have much to offer because I dont use this workflow

Comment: `vim some_other_directory` worked by adding `exe 'cd '.argv()[0]` to the body of the first condition in the if statement. the answer has been edited.